# Rails 5: nested resources undefined method _path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables: users, observative_sessions and observations.

In each respective model there's

users.rb

```
has_many :observative_sessions, dependent: :destroy
has_many :observations, through: :observative_sessions, dependent: :destroy
```

observative_sessions.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :observations, dependent: :destroy
```

observations.rb

```
belongs_to :observative_session
belongs_to :user
```

In routes.rb I nested observations in observative_sessions

```
resources :observative_sessions do
  resources :observations
end
```

I show the list of possible observations for each observative_session so I created the partial (observations/_index.html.erb) to render in the show page of observative session.

```
<%= render 'observations/index' %>
```

and a button to create new observations

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-observation-modal">Create</button>
```

observative_sessions_controller.rb

```
def show
   @q = Observation.ransack([:observative_session])
   @observations = @s.result.order(params[:order]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:q].present?
   @observations = @s.result.order(params[:order]).paginate(page: params[:page]) unless params[:q].present?
   @observation = Observation.new
end
```

Now I have a problem, when I try to create a new observation the button calls the new_modal which renders the form

```
<%= render 'observations/form' %>
```

observations/_form.html.erb

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for ([@observative_session, @observation]) do |f| %>
```

And here I get the error Undefined method 'observations_path'
This is how I defined the creation method in observations_controller.rb

```
def create
  @observation = Observation.new(observation_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @observation.save
    format.html { redirect_to [@observative_session, @observation], notice: 'Observation was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @observation }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @observation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad the error was on new.html.erb I passed

```
<%= render 'form', observation: @observation %>
```

instead of

```
<%= render 'form', observation: ([@observative_session, @observation]) %>
```

and in observations_controller.rb I had to add

```
    @observative_session = ObservativeSession.find(params[:observative_session_id])
    @observation = @observative_session.observations.build(observation_params)
```

By the way before I was trying to use thinking of passing the id of the session

```
ObservativeSession.find(params[:id])
```

instead it should be

```
ObservativeSession.find(params[:observative_session_id])
```